# Accessing values inside a span with JS and DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

i need help figuring out if it's possible with JS and DOM store in a variable an img tag inside ina a span using document.getElementById

Scenario:

```
<span id="main-image"> <img src="img/truck.png" > </span>
```

Basically I need to store  in a variable called image.

Someone can help me ?

Thx a lot

Luke

Answer (score 1):

Why not use querySelector instead ?

```
var image = document.querySelector('#main-image img');
```

or if you just have to use getElementById

```
var image = getElementById('main-image').getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
```